# What kind of view is the Google Pay popup?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-view, google-pay

How Google Pay opens up a payment sheet as bottom popup (see image bellow) and communicate with the website to notify when payment is done?

Is it a deeplink using scheme such as `googlepay://...` or an Intent using iframe as defined [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/multidevice/android/intents/)? Or it's something else.

I'm wondering if this kind of popup can be displayed by any application for other purpose.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a BottomSheetDialogFragment, and yes you can use it in your application.
Read this [article](https://medium.com/@kosta.palash/using-bottomsheetdialogfragment-with-material-design-guideline-f9814c39b9fc) for more

Comment: Thanks! I have one more question regarding this, does this fragment can be openned outside of the application like does Google Pay, from an app link or a deep link?

Comment: After a second check and guess, I feel like the way Google Pay works is that it is coded inside Chrome application in order to create this bottom popup from inside Chrome App. I thought this popup was the Google Pay application (the one installed in my phone) that openned up, it seems to not work as I guessed in the first place.